# How to set a value to sequence?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

How to set value to sequence in **plpgsql** ?

This fails in  **plpgsql**

```
select setval('public.student_id', select max(student_id) from public.student);
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, you are correct, it is possible to use a subquery. As you point out in your answer it just needs to be surrounded by parentheses, so: `select setval('public.student_id', (select max(student_id) from public.student));`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this instead, imagining `public.student_id` is the name of sequence that already exists:

```
select setval('public.student_id',max(student_id))
from public.student;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is surround the subquery with parentheses. That is syntactically required.